# iPhone Dev - Scrolling to a new position in a tableview that is currently off-screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Say for example I have a tab bar controller where one of its views is a tableviewcontroller, and another one is some other view. The other view has a button in it that when pressed, should make it so the tableview (which is not on the screen while you're pressing the button) repositions itself so that some specified cell is now the top one being displayed when the tableview is again displayed.

My question is this: can I just call [myTableVC.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:someIndex] from inside the other class when the button is pushed? Or does the view actually have to be on the screen when scrollToRowAtIndexPath is called for it to change the top cell that will be displayed?

Comment: So basically you are trying to scroll a tableview that is currently not seen from another viewcontroller?

Comment: This isn't actually exactly what I'm doing. I just gave this as a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, just so I could understand if this type of thing would work.

Comment: If you are trying to get one viewcontroller to talk to the next you can use the nsnotification class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to, but you probably shouldn’t—calling `view` or `tableView` on an offscreen view controller may cause its view to get loaded into memory unnecessarily. Just set a property—a CGFloat or whatever—on the view controller for the scroll position that it *should* be at when it appears, and scroll to that position in the controller’s `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear:animated:`.